Are these lines in my toilet bowl signs of a (impending?) structural failure?
There are some lines in my toilet bowl and would appreciate if I can get an advice if the lines inside of my toilet bowl are just normal wear and tear or is it a sign to replace it soon due to it's age of ~12 years? Thank you

EDIT:
Thanks all, it isn't hair as I have been trying to brush it off with a brush and Mr Muscle but it isn't coming off... There is no movement of the toilet bowl. There are lines on the outside of the toilet bowl although they are not directly opposite the lines on the inside. I will get a new toilet bowl, thanks

Unless those lines are hair, replace now.  Hair will move if you run your finger across it.  Toilets don't really age.  They might have defects or be damaged or get clogged.

it is not normal

Any movement of the toilet?    Porcelain is not strong if not on a solid floor/base.  Movement or being anchored to the floor too tight can cause cracks.  Cracks in something that holds water/stuff is not good for staying dry.

Is there a corresponding line on the outside? - that would pretty much prove it's a crack.

@crip659: Those are certainly not hairs! Click the picture to get a larger version: the cracks are connected up, joining at right angles. Hairs don't do that. Replace ASAP!

If that breaks while you are sitting on it, the full weight of your body will descend on the razor sharp edges of the broken porcelain.
You could sever a femoral artery and bleed out lying in a pool of urine and feces.
If you can feel the cracks with your finger, replace it.  If they are just marks from a plunger or brush, you'll probably be OK.
But they look like cracks to me.

There goes my lunch.  You forgot puke.
